# Why is firebase functions deployment extremly slow?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I run the command "firebase deploy --only functions" it takes around 1 minute to deploy my function even if I didn't update my function.
Am I doing something wrong?
Could it be because of the node_modules folder in my functions folder?
Is function deployment in firebase just slow?
Console Log:

```
C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\myProject> firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'myProject'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (36.96 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 (Beta) function myFunction(europe-west1)...
i  scheduler: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  scheduler: all necessary APIs are enabled
+  pubsub: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: scheduler job firebase-schedule-myFunction-europe-west1 is up to date, no changes required
+  functions[myFunction(europe-west1)]: Successful update operation.

+  Deploy complete!
```

It usually gets stuck for 1 minute on this line:

```
i  functions: scheduler job firebase-schedule-svt-europe-west1 is up to date, no changes required
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed at Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: If you're deploying frequently to test your functions, you may wish to check out the local emulator, which hot reloads any changes you make.

Comment: If you have a need to make frequent changes to the logic on the cloud, then one possible solution is to store JavaScript code inside a Database or Storage service, and then have Cloud Function download and `eval()` it (this has security implications, so make sure to only run trusted code and protect the code storage from unauthorized modifications).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1-2 minutes is typical. Unlike some other FaaS providers, Cloud Functions is actually running `npm install` and building the `node_modules` in the cloud, which does take some time but also means you don't need to worry about cross-compiling native dependencies.

Cloud Functions doesn't know if you updated your function or not, so it does a fresh redeploy every time.

My recommendation is to ONLY update the functions you changed. You can do this with the following:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:specificFunctionName,functions:anotherFunctionName,etc
```

This should speed things up at least a little bit, but probably not a lot.

Comment: It should cache the node_modules based on package-lock.json

Comment: Just to add a comment to this command it's actually 
firebase deploy --only functions:specificFunctionName,functions:anotherFunctionName,...

make sure to add "functions:" after the comma and before the name of the function for each function you're deploying.