# How to turn off installation and build when deploying firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Everytime a firebase function is deployed, [it seems that google cloud is running npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260168/why-is-firebase-functions-deployment-extremly-slow) and then recently has started running `npm run build` if it exists (which started breaking my deployment). I've renamed `npm run build` to `npm run bundle` for now but how can I turn both of these off? I will push up a pre-bundled version of the app so I don't need cloud functions to do anything! Where can I configure this?